# How to run an existing Ruby script in a Java project using JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, scripting, jruby

I am trying to run an existing Ruby script in a Java project with JRuby. All the examples I have found write a Ruby script on the fly and run it like so:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
container.runScriptlet("puts 'hello world'");
```

However I would like to run an existing Ruby script. Haven't had any luck. Here's what I've been trying:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
container.runScriptlet("/path/to/file/test.rb");
```

My `test.rb` file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby

puts "hi"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [the API docs](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/embed/ScriptingContainer.html), `runScriptlet` has several forms; if you want it to execute a file, it needs [two parameters](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/embed/ScriptingContainer.html#runScriptlet(org.jruby.embed.PathType,%20java.lang.String)); in your case,

```
container.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE, "/path/to/file/test.rb");
```

tl;dr: When in doubt, check the docs.